# ActiveRecord association seems to read differently depending on reading forward or backward

Tags: activerecord, database-design

I've read a ton of ActiveRecord SO Questions and haven't come across this yet. I know that the following code snippet is a little long winded but I'm not using Rails so I wanted to be clear about how my database was created/structured.

A household has the head (or heads) of household (like mom and dad), and it has children. Mom, Dad and the kids are all members of the household. I tried to implement that as follows. This is the full code snippet so you can just copy and paste and run it if you have active_record and sqlite3.

I wrote the question in-line in the code, but here it is in case you don't want to skim the code: **when I do household.heads I get the members which I assigned as heads of household. But when I run member.household.heads (on the same household!) I don't get the heads, I get the kids!** My only thought is that I shouldn't be using two 'has_many's with the same foreign_key, but everything else I've tried doesn't work.

```rb
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(File.open('database.log', 'w'))

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'sqlite3',
  :database => 'test.db'
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'members'
    create_table :members do |table|
      table.integer :household_id
      table.integer :head_id
      table.integer :child_id
      table.string :name
    end
  end

  unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include? 'households'
    create_table :households do |table|
      table.string :address
    end
  end
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :household
end

class Household < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :heads, class_name: "Member", foreign_key: :household_id
  has_many :children, class_name: "Member", foreign_key: :household_id
end

#Create some members
m1 = Member.create(name: "Foo")
m2 = Member.create(name: "Bar") #Foo's wife
m3 = Member.create(name: "foo-foo") #Foo and Bar's little girl

#Create a household
h1 = Household.create(address: "123 Fake St.")

#Assign members to households
h1.heads = [m1, m2]
h1.children = [m3]


#first let's check, h1 is m1's household. The two are the same.
p h1.id == m1.household.id

#So why doesn't this work? 
h1.heads.each{|head| p head.name} #returns Foo and Bar
m1.household.heads.each{|head| p head.name} #<= Doesn't return Foo and Bar ?!?
h1.children.each{|child| p child.name} #returns foo-foo
m1.household.children.each{|child| p child.name} #Also returns foo-foo as expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, ActiveRecord is not OK with two Models of the same class being referred to by the same foreign key (household_id). You're just overwriting the assignment of h1's members when you assign children (or something like that, this still isn't clear to me).

You either need different classes: Head and Child or you need to be ok with the child calling the household differently.

I ended up changing the foreign keys to: household_id and house_id since I need heads.household more than I need child.household

(I still think it is annoying to use children.house but oh well!)

To be clear:

```
class Household < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :heads, class_name: "Member", foreign_key: :household_id
  has_many :children, class_name: "Member", foreign_key: :house_id  
end
```